# Android: How to get system preference values

Tags: android, android-preferences

How do I get the value of Android system preferences/settings (i.e. not one defined by myself), for example whether the phone is currently in silent mode or not?.

I've been trying to look for a list of system preference keys but have not been able to find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) contains the the list of system settings and methods to set and get their values.